# can't connect to mysql database using host,user and pass

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this whenever I run the below code:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\wamp\www\php-academy\113-connect-db.php

---

```
    <?php
    $conn_error ='could not connect';
    $mysql_host = 'localhost';
    $mysql_user = 'root';
    $mysql_pass = '';
    mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or                                                   die($conn_error);

    $mysql_db = 'a_database';

    mysql_select_db($mysql_db) or die($conn_error);
    echo 'Connected!';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is because the extension is not loaded.  I would check your php_info(); to find out.

Once you do your code should work, although I prefer to assign the mysql_connect() to a variable and then call that variable in mysql_select_db() as I have below:

```
$defHost     = 'localhost';
$defUsername = 'username';
$defPassword = 'password';
$defDatabase = 'database_name';

$connect = mysql_connect($defHost, $defUsername, $defPassword) or die();
mysql_select_db($defDatabase, $connect) or die();
```

Comment: hey Thanks Josh how would I go about loading in the extension? I checked the phpinfo() function but not sure what i should be looking for and not sure what i should be doing afterwards to get the extension to load.

Comment: nm got it - I went to the php.ini file and found ;extension=php_mysql.dll and took out the semicolon.

Answer (score 4):

That probably means you don't have the MySQL extension loaded. You can test whether the extension is loaded with `extension_loaded("mysql");`.

Comment: I guess you beat me to the punch. :P

Comment: Thanks Jelle. I tested the extension_loaded("mysql") like u suggested. How would I load it?

Comment: You'll probably have to recompile PHP with --enable-mysql or some similar option. Alternatively, you can use the [dl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for the error may be the following:

Incorrect access details to server database are specified in configuration file. 
There are no read permissions for configuration file. Provide read permissions for the file.